# How can I install a webapp extension AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86 using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

After installing the latest Az module in Powershell I can install the webapp extension *AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86* using the following command:

```
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName '<resource-group>' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions' -Name '<webapp-name>/AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86' -ApiVersion '2018-02-01'
```

Now I want the same results using azure-cli:

```
az resource create --resource-group '<resource-group>' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions' --name '<webapp-name>/AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86' --api-version '2018-02-01'
```

but when executed it requires an extra argument *--properties* but I cann't find any documentation regarding this argument. If I provide an empty json object the operation fails:

> az : ERROR: Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: 404
>   Client Error: Not Found for url ....

How can I solve this problem using Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--name` should be `--name '<webapp-name>/siteextensions/AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86'`, also append `--properties '{}'`.

Try the sample as below, it works fine on my side.

```
az resource create --resource-group '<resource-group>' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions' --name '<webapp-name>/siteextensions/AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86' --api-version '2018-02-01' --properties '{}'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. It is still a bit strange that executing 'az resource list' does not show the endresult. 'az resource show' using 'resource-type' and 'name' does show the created resource information.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Not sure, I didn't test with `az resource list` and `az resource show`, I refresh my azure portal and see it has been created successfully in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `--properties {}`

If their aren't actually any mandatory properties this will make CLI happy